# Query taking a long time to run. Any way to simplify it?

Tags: sql, hive, hue

i'm running the code as follows. I'm having trouble with the long running time. Is there a way to make it run faster?

```
SELECT
a.data_date as day
, sum(a.column1) + sum(a.column2) as total
, sum(a.column1) as part1
, sum(a.column2) as part2
, sum(b.column1) as alien

FROM table1 a

INNER JOIN table1 b

ON a.data_date = b.data_date AND a.column3 = b.column3

WHERE a.data_date ='20131001'
and a.column3 = 12345
and a.column4 is not NULL
and b.column4 is NULL

GROUP BY
a.data_date
```

Comment: No doubt creating an index *could* help. Have you tried running an execution plan? Hit Ctrl+L in SQL server to see the execution plan. It will tell you where the bulk of the resource went to run the query, and where an index could improve it. Keep in mind it just tells you what would improve *that* query, not your whole database.

Comment: It looks pretty clean...as long as the self join is producing 1 row for each table1 record (is a.data_date + a.column3 unique?)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see it you don't need the `JOIN` at all.
You can get th same result with single reference to your table.

Comment: The thing is that by using a.column4 is not NULL and b.column4 is NULL, it'll give me different column1 data, which is what i'm looking for

Comment: Something like `SELECT
a.data_date as day
, sum(a.column1) + sum(a.column2) as total
, sum(a.column1) as part1
, sum(a.column2) as part2
FROM table1 a
WHERE a.data_date ='20131001'
and a.column3 = 12345
and a.column4 is not NULL
GROUP BY
a.data_date
` will give you most of your result, maybe add a subquery for `, sum(b.column1) as alien`

Answer (score 0):

Since this is the same table,i believe u can remove your join, the best is provide ur sample data and expected result, then we can help u better, cheer =)

```
SELECT
a.data_date as day
, sum(a.column1) + sum(a.column2) as total
, sum(a.column1) as part1
, sum(a.column2) as part2
--remove this
--, sum(b.column1) as alien

FROM table1 a

--remove this
--INNER JOIN table1 b

--ON a.data_date = b.data_date AND a.column3 = b.column3

WHERE a.data_date ='20131001'
and a.column3 = 12345


and a.column4 is not NULL
--remove this
--and b.column4 is NULL

GROUP BY
a.data_date,a.column3
```

Answer (score 0):

optimization techniques also depend on the size of tables.

small table should be first and try to put that table on distributed cache.

to make it faster ,rather applying where condition after join,try to apply it before join so that your join will be faster.

you may try something like below

```
set hive.auto.convert.join.true;
select
a.data_date as day
, sum(a.column1) + sum(a.column2) as total
, sum(a.column1) as part1
, sum(a.column2) as part2
, sum(b.column1) as alien
from table1 b
inner join (select * from table1 WHERE a.data_date ='20131001'
and a.column3 = 12345
and a.column4 is not NULL
)a
on (a.data_date = b.data_date AND a.column3 = b.column3)

where b.column4 is NULL
GROUP BY
a.data_date
```